# ggplot2: change break points of discrete scale to be between two break points

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggproto

I have the following dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(dens = rnorm(5000),
             split = as.factor(sample(1:2, 5000, replace = T)),
             method = as.factor(sample(c("A","B"), 5000, replace = T)),
             counts = sample(c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000), 5000, replace = T))
```

I have the following split violin plots for splits 1 and 2 within groups A and B for each count. We have four groups for each setting but there is a nested aspect to it:

```
library(ggplot2)
GeomSplitViolin <- ggproto("GeomSplitViolin", GeomViolin, 
                           draw_group = function(self, data, ..., draw_quantiles = NULL){
                               ## By @YAK: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35717353/split-violin-plot-with-ggplot2
                               data <- transform(data, xminv = x - violinwidth * (x - xmin), xmaxv = x + violinwidth * (xmax - x))
                               grp <- data[1,'group']
                               newdata <- plyr::arrange(transform(data, x = if(grp%%2==1) xminv else xmaxv), if(grp%%2==1) y else -y)
                               newdata <- rbind(newdata[1, ], newdata, newdata[nrow(newdata), ], newdata[1, ])
                               newdata[c(1,nrow(newdata)-1,nrow(newdata)), 'x'] <- round(newdata[1, 'x']) 
                               if (length(draw_quantiles) > 0 & !scales::zero_range(range(data$y))) {
                                   stopifnot(all(draw_quantiles >= 0), all(draw_quantiles <= 1))
                                   quantiles <- create_quantile_segment_frame(data, draw_quantiles, split = TRUE, grp = grp)
                                   aesthetics <- data[rep(1, nrow(quantiles)), setdiff(names(data), c("x", "y")), drop = FALSE]
                                   aesthetics$alpha <- rep(1, nrow(quantiles))
                                   both <- cbind(quantiles, aesthetics)
                                   quantile_grob <- GeomPath$draw_panel(both, ...)
                                   ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", grid::grobTree(GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...), quantile_grob))
                               }
                               else {
                                   ggplot2:::ggname("geom_split_violin", GeomPolygon$draw_panel(newdata, ...))
                               }
                           }
                           )

create_quantile_segment_frame <- function (data, draw_quantiles, split = FALSE, grp = NULL) {
    dens <- cumsum(data$density)/sum(data$density)
    ecdf <- stats::approxfun(dens, data$y)
    ys <- ecdf(draw_quantiles)
    violin.xminvs <- (stats::approxfun(data$y, data$xminv))(ys)
    violin.xmaxvs <- (stats::approxfun(data$y, data$xmaxv))(ys)
    violin.xs <- (stats::approxfun(data$y, data$x))(ys)
    if (grp %% 2 == 0) {
        data.frame(x = ggplot2:::interleave(violin.xs, violin.xmaxvs), 
                   y = rep(ys, each = 2), group = rep(ys, each = 2)) 
    } else {
        data.frame(x = ggplot2:::interleave(violin.xminvs, violin.xs), 
                   y = rep(ys, each = 2), group = rep(ys, each = 2)) 
    }
}

geom_split_violin <- function (mapping = NULL, data = NULL, stat = "ydensity", position = "identity", ..., draw_quantiles = NULL, trim = TRUE, scale = "area", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, inherit.aes = TRUE) {
    layer(data = data, mapping = mapping, stat = stat, geom = GeomSplitViolin, position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes, params = list(trim = trim, scale = scale, draw_quantiles = draw_quantiles, na.rm = na.rm, ...))
}



df$key <- factor(paste(df$split, df$method))

levels(df$split) <- factor(0:2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = interaction(split, counts), y = dens, fill = key)) +geom_split_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) +scale_fill_manual(values=RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name="Paired",n=4)) + theme_light() + theme(legend.position="bottom") + scale_x_discrete(limits=levels(interaction(df$split,df$counts))[-length(levels(interaction(df$split,df$counts)))],drop = FALSE, name = "Counts")
```

And I get the following:

[image]

Which is great, except that I would like to only have labels of counts 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000 on the x-axis and in between the blue and the green violin plots. So label 1 in between the first blue and the green violin plots, 10 in between the second blue and the green violin plots, 100  in between the second blue and the green violin plots and so on.

Thanks for any suggestions on how to do this.

Comment: have a look at that one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255322/ggplot-different-position-for-ticks-and-labels-on-x-axis-in-grouped-bar-plot

Comment: and this one might also help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44616530/axis-labels-on-two-lines-with-nested-x-variables-year-below-months

Comment: Can't really answer your question, but I seriously like your plot.

Comment: Thanks! I am not sure how to get what I want to work though.

Comment: The example is self-contained. If you run it, you get df.

Comment: The edits which I suggested were 1) correcting your code (your df <- assignment is incorrect,  a comma is missing) and 2) for readability. It's not really great to have the code without any line break. It makes the code much more readable if you break it ,e.g. after the plus signs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually solve these issues with facets, then format the strips as though they are axis labels. This also naturally puts the pairs closer together, without any hacks, and you can change the distance by changing `theme(panel.spacing = .....)`, if needed. E.g.:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = split, y = dens, fill = key)) +
  geom_split_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name="Paired",n=4)) + 
  xlab('count') +
  facet_grid(~counts, scales = 'free_x', switch = 'x') +
  theme_light() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text = element_text(color = 'black'))
```

[image]

Or a different theme with less obvious facets:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = split, y = dens, fill = key)) +
  geom_split_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name="Paired",n=4)) + 
  xlab('count') +
  facet_grid(~counts, scales = 'free_x', switch = 'x') +
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Can there be a larger gap between the "counts" for the second plot? Also, "bounding box" around axes would be worth trying.
"

Comment: Yes, by changing `theme(panel.spacing = .....)`, as stated in the answer...

Comment: Thanks! I don't like the fact that the lines do not continue acrorss the figure, however. I guess we can not put an overall bounding box?

Comment: I have grown to like your second answer more and more out of the three answers. Btw, is it possible to have colour of blue and green for the 1 and 2, and light and dark hue (I guess this would be light gray for A and dark gray for B) in the legend?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of changing the break point for a discrete scale, you can try adding a text layer to the plot itself, which is able to accept non-integer values for discrete scale positions:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = x, y = dens, fill = key)) + 
  geom_split_violin(draw_quantiles = c(0.25, 0.5, 0.75)) +

  # annotate layer with non-integer positions
  annotate(geom = "text", x = c(1.5, 4.5, 7.5, 10.5, 13.5), y = -3.75,
           label = c("1", "10", "100", "1000", "10000")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(name="Paired", n=4)) + 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Counts", drop = FALSE) +
  theme_minimal() + 

  # hide the actual discrete labels / ticks
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image: plot]

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for this! I will wait for some more responses and see if other options come up!

Comment: Can one annotate below the x-axis? Btw, x = interaction(split, counts) in your call to ggplot2.