# Plot lists of time series data for factors in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, data-science, data-visualization

I have a series of lists describing duration (in days) of events, and I would like to plot this data as lines to compare the lists.

Below is some example data on what lunch options were served on which days at school. I have already parsed my data and this is the reduced form. Originally it was in the form of complex character strings.

```
soup = c(15:18)
grilledcheese = c(0:19)
pasta = c(3:13)
```

I want to create a graph similar to this one, with days on the x axis and `soup`, `grilled cheese`, and `pasta` on the y axis:
[image]

I looked online and I'm not sure what kind of graph to use for this. Part of the difficulty is that the data does not start at 0 and the y axis should represent factors.

What I tried:

I tried plotting this in ggplot but it only takes data frames. I am wondering if there is a way to plot directly from lists. It seems like there should be a straightforward solution here that maybe I am missing.

I also tried this

`plot(x = grilledcheese, y = rep(1, length(grilledcheese)))`

which is closer to what I want, but I'm not sure how to plot multiple factors on the y axis.

Comment: What did you try? What step are you struggling with? Is there a reason the data is not in a data.frame? Could you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610)? P.S. especially if this is a homework (and it *looks* a lot like one ;) you should show some previous work [see also here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: This is actually not homework, although I can see why you think that. I am a PhD student plotting clinical data on the progression of disease in patients, so "grilledcheese" might actually correspond to "fever" or "headache." I started with some more convoluted character strings describing days symptoms were experienced and have reduced it to the lists of numbers described above. The image is of a graph published 20 years ago which I am trying to recreate with the updated data. I will provide some more info in the original post as well. Thanks for your response and any help you can provide!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's get your data in a shape easier to handle with ggplot2:

```
library(tidyverse)    
soup = c(15:18)
grilledcheese = c(0:19)
pasta = c(3:13)


df <- data.frame(soup_min = c(min(soup),max(soup)),
                 grilledcheese = c(min(grilledcheese),max(grilledcheese)),
                 pasta = c(min(pasta),max(pasta)))

df <- pivot_longer(df, cols = 1:3) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  mutate(minv = min(value),
         maxv = max(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-value) %>% 
  distinct()
```

### Data

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  name           minv  maxv
  <chr>         <int> <int>
1 soup_min         15    18
2 grilledcheese     0    19
3 pasta             3    13
```

### Graph

We can then plot the different elements you want: the starting and ending dots for each line, the lines themselves and the axis theme.

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = minv, xend = maxv, y = name, yend = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = minv, y = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = maxv, y = name)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:20),
                     labels = c(0:20),
                     limits = c(0,20),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = 1),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length =unit(.25, "cm"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 1),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "")
```

We get this:

[image: First_graph]

This should do the trick.

#### Extra custom

Now, if you want to have the ticks labels in-between the ticks, you might want to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255322/how-to-plot-x-axis-labels-and-bars-between-tick-marks-in-ggplot2-bar-plot) because you will have to reshape your data, and get the graph done once you have all the food types you want. Until, I just add spacing with-in the labels :

```
ggplot(df) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = minv, xend = maxv, y = name, yend = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = minv, y = name)) +
  geom_point(aes(x = maxv, y = name)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:20),
                     labels = paste("         ",0:20),
                     limits = c(0,20),
                     expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(size = 1),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.length =unit(.25, "cm"),
        axis.line.x = element_line(size = 1),
        panel.background = element_blank()) +
  labs(x = "",
       y = "")
```

[image: Graph2]

Answer (score 1):

You will first need to engineer your data into a data frame. You could do, e.g.

```
soup = c(15:18)
grilledcheese = c(0:19)
pasta = c(3:13)

## make dataframe

library(tidyverse)
my_x_axis <- as_tibble(seq(0,20)) 
names(my_x_axis) <- 'x'
my_x_axis %>% mutate(soup_y = 1*ifelse(as.numeric(x %in% soup) == 1, 1, NA)) %>% 
              mutate(grilledcheese_y = 2*ifelse(as.numeric(x %in% grilledcheese) == 1, 1, NA)) %>% 
              mutate(pasta_y = 3*ifelse(as.numeric(x %in% pasta) == 1, 1, NA))  -> data
```

Here, I use the knowledge that your x axis values are between 0 and 20. You could also do choose them by, e.g. by `min(c(soup,grilledcheese,pasta))` and `min(c(soup,grilledcheese,pasta))` or some other logic.

Following the idea from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68932022/how-do-i-dodge-error-bars-and-points-issues-using-the-position-argument/68934003#68934003), I hard-code the y axis positions for the three foods as 1, 2, and 3.

The ggplot command reads as:

```
library(ggplot2)              
ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x = x, y=soup_y)) +
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x = x, y=grilledcheese_y)) +
  geom_line(data=data, aes(x = x, y=pasta_y)) + 
  scale_y_discrete(labels = NULL, breaks = NULL) + labs(y = "") +  ## drop y axis labels 
  scale_x_continuous(labels=seq(0,20,1), breaks=seq(0,20,1)) + # x axis tick marks
  geom_text(aes(label = c('soup','grilledcheese','pasta'), x = 0, y = c(1,2,3), vjust = -.2,hjust=-.3)) # add labels
```

[image: output]