# Plotting x-axis labels between bars not working with coord flip

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, geom-bar

I need to change x-axis ticks to be between sets of dodged bars in a ggplot barplot that has been rotated using coord flip.

This question has a solution that works brilliantly up to the point of coord_flip()
[How to plot x-axis labels and bars between tick marks in ggplot2 bar plot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44255322/how-to-plot-x-axis-labels-and-bars-between-tick-marks-in-ggplot2-bar-plot)

but then the code puts tick marks at the x(now Y) axis labels AS WELL as between the groups.... can anyone explain why and what to do about it....

```
    ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = value, fill = variable)) + 
geom_col(position = "dodge") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(sort(unique(data$x)), x_tick),
                 labels = c(sort(unique(data$name)), rep(c(""), len))) +
theme(axis.ticks.x = element_line(color = c(rep(NA, len -1), rep("black",len))))+coord_flip()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

When using `coord_flip` you have to set `axis.ticks.y` in `theme`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data <- data.frame(
  name = c("X", "Y", "Z"),
  A = c(2, 4, 6),
  B = c(1, 3, 4),
  C = c(3, 4, 5)
)
data <- reshape2::melt(data, id = 1)

data$x <- as.integer(as.factor(data$name))
x_tick <- c(0, unique(data$x)) + 0.5
len <- length(x_tick)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge") +
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = c(sort(unique(data$x)), x_tick),
    labels = c(sort(unique(data$name)), rep(c(""), len))
  ) +
  theme(axis.ticks.y = element_line(color = c(
    rep(NA, len - 1),
    rep("black", len)
  ))) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Or as a second option, get rid of `coord_flip` by switching `x` and `y` and setting `orientation="y"` in `geom_col`:

```r
ggplot(data, aes(y = x, x = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", orientation = "y") +
  scale_y_continuous(
    breaks = c(sort(unique(data$x)), x_tick),
    labels = c(sort(unique(data$name)), rep(c(""), len))
  ) +
  theme(
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(
      color = c(rep(NA, len - 1), rep("black", len))
    )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: That's great!  Thanks - 
I am somewhat confused as to what coord_flip changes and what it doesn't now......
and it is still not working in my much more complicated real world (and unreproducible example/case) but this now gives me hope and direction!
:-)